How do I know how many enemies have I not found in the Hunter's Journal?
In Hollow Knight, there is an item called the Hunter's Journal. Essentially, it's an enemy log, that shows every enemy in the game, their appearance, and a short description by the Hunter (who gives the journal).
Is there any way to know how many enemies I haven't found yet, besides finding a full list of enemies on the internet and going through them one by one, or repeatedly going back to the Hunter to check if I've finished the journal yet?

There is a way to see your Journal progress in-game.  Just outside the chamber for the final boss fight (accessible after getting all three Dreamers), you can gain the ability "World Sense", which shows your game completion percentage in the Inventory screen and also shows your Journal progress in the Journal screen.
Specifically, the bottom-right of the Journal will show an "Encountered" value (in the form "[number encountered so far] / [total available]"), showing how many enemies you have entries for (usually earned the first time you kill such an enemy) and a "Completed" value (in the form "[number completed so far] / [total available]"), showing how many you have unlocked the Hunter's notes for (via killing a certain quantity of the enemy).
Note that there are a small number of Journal entries that are not required for (being rewarded for) completing the Journal.  These entries are not included in the "total available" count unless they're already present in your Journal.

If I have killed enemies I'm not required to, would they be added to the amount of enemies I've completed in the journal, meaning I could accidentally think I've finished it? Also, is it possible to get the World Sense pseudo-ability and then leave without fighting the Hollow Knight?

@Daemons "If I have killed enemies I'm not required to" — Doing this causes both the "number encountered" and "total number" values to go up by 1 for each such entry, so if you're missing any entries, you'll always be able to tell by the fact that the first number is less than the second.  "Is it possible to get the World Sense pseudo-ability and then leave without fighting the Hollow Knight?" — Yes.
